# creating a filter using the gdata java client library and email settings api

Tags: google-email-settings-api

This is my first time with google apis and I am having trouble implementing the email settings api in eclipse .Please tell me exactly which jar files are to be included and how ? I am getting GmailSettingsService class not found error.Please Help 
Thank you

Comment: What have you done so far? All the settings can be found in their **[sample application](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/)**

Answer (score 0):

From **[here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/wiki/EclipsePlugin)**:

> Didn't you ever want some kind of tool to create new Google Data projects in seconds? Google Data Java Client Eclipse
>   Plug-in is now available for use.
>
> Using this plug-in you can create a new Java project to interact with
>   any Google Data API of your choice. Now, you don't need to worry about
>   setting up the dependencies for your Google Data project. This plug-in
>   handles all the dependencies and also provides you with an option to
>   download the external dependencies. It also creates a boiler plate
>   code to interact with the API that you are interested in. This will
>   give a quick start to all the newbies.

Comment: yeah I installed the plug-in,I am getting error in 
import com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.LogRecord.Level;
import com.google.apphosting.datastore.EntityV4.PartitionId.Constants;
in GmailSettingsService class